# Как и чем лучше парсить сайт с SPA на питоне?

Tags: python, requests, web-scraping

Есть такой  [сайт](https://www.atptour.com) я хочу спарсить данные об этом игроке по этой [ссылке](https://www.atptour.com/en/players/felix-auger-aliassime/ag37/player-stats?year=0&surfaceType=all)

Написал для этого такой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html():
    r = requests.get(url='https://www.atptour.com/en/players/felix-auger-aliassime/ag37/overview')
    return r.text
html = get_html()

def get_career(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    career = soup.find('tr')
    print(career)


get_career(html)
```

Но вот в чем дело,ту ссылку которую я парщу является одностраничным приложением
и соотвественно данные которые мне нужны [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не приходят в полном html коде страницы.

Как можно и чем лучше парсить сайты с SPA?

Comment: Изучить, как именно SPA получает данные, и уже исходя из этого выбирать инструмент

Comment: Если я правильно про анализировал сайт то по сути большинство верстки сайта генерится динамически JS-ом и  генерация вроде происходит в браузере

Comment: Зачем вам вёрстка, вы изучите откуда данные берутся, без всяких вёрсток. Они же не из воздуха генерируются JS-ом, наверное?

Comment: Но вообще-то это не SPA, я открыл страницу https://www.atptour.com/en/players/felix-auger-aliassime/ag37/player-stats и всё там в html-коде все данные с вашего скриншота замечательно присутствуют и отображаются даже при отключенном JS

Comment: Хмм странно,у меня они не отображаются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedrv\\chromedriver.exe'   # путь к драйверу может быть любым
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=chromedriver)
# browser.implicitly_wait(20)
browser.get('https://www.atptour.com/en/players/felix-auger-aliassime/ag37/player-stats')
mtlist = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('mega-table')
for mt in  mtlist:
    print(mt.text + '\n')
```

Вариант парсинга с использованием библиотеки Selenium и браузера Chrome.