# Как парсить ссылку если нет классы python requests

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Добого времени суток! Нужно сделать парсер [сайта](https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing).
Мне нужно получить текст заголовка что являеться ссылкой, но в теге  нет никакого href или класса тег только в div class="mainTitle___mbpq1" но я никак не могу получить заголовок.
Пробовал этот способ:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

resp = req.get('https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing').text
print(resp)


def get_catalog_data(html):
    soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
    knifes = soup.find('a')

    print(knifes)


get_catalog_data(resp)
```

выводить None

Если просто хочу вывести весь html то не выводиться весь

[image: Не выводиться весь раскрытый]

Он просто как будто бы пустой

Как решить?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение с помощью библиотеки selenium

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


EXE_PATH = r'C:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH)
while True:
    driver.get('https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a').text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Указанный сайт полностью построен на скриптах. То есть, чтобы увидеть страницу необходимо её открыть. Обычно используют для этих целей Selenium([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064080/Как-и-чем-лучше-парсить-сайт-с-spa-на-питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064080/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D1%81-spa-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5)), но можно пойти другим путем.

Можно через "инструменты разработчика"- "сети", подсмотреть куда уходит запрос при нажатии нажатии на "ссылку".
В твоем случае, ссылка, которая возвращает json-ответ c содержанием всей информации (список доступных листингов, заголовки, ссылки на них) - https://www.kucoin.com/_api/cms/articles?page=1&pageSize=10&category=listing&lang=ru_RU.

Инструменты разработчика открыть - «Ctrl» + «Shift» + «I».

Скриншоты места, где посмотреть ссылку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также на всякий случай оставлю ссылку на одного листинга в списке- https://assets.staticimg.com/cms/articles/ru-kucoinfutures-launched-aave-ksm-contracts.json?t=9060078